# reactjs application - can't get my hello world to show up

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

**Background / Problem**

I'm trying to build understand my first react/webpack/nodejs app.  I am able to build / launch it by opening a browser and navigating to http://localhost:3333/ , but the hello world message I'm expecting is not showing.  Instead I think it's trying to give me a directory listing of a folder...? Not too sure but all I see is "~/"

**npm run dev results**

```
me@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial$ npm run dev

> reactjstutorial@1.0.0 dev /mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial
> webpack-dev-server

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3333/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial/build
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: e855fbe9a7da7f9b8f40
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 1854ms
Built at: 06/28/2020 8:37:19 PM
        Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
    bundle.js  1.26 MiB    main  [emitted]        main
bundle.js.map  1.46 MiB    main  [emitted] [dev]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js bundle.js.map
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 ./app/index.jsx 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./app/index.jsx] 3.47 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js] 135 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:3333] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 4.29 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.91 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
    + 29 hidden modules
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/build')
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/app')

var config = {
        entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
        mode: 'development',
        output: {
                path: BUILD_DIR,
                filename: 'bundle.js',
                publicPath: '/'
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        devServer: {
                inline: true,
                contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
                port: 3333
        },

        module: {
                rules: [
                        {
                                test: /\.jsx?/,
                                include: APP_DIR,
                                loader: 'babel-loader'
                        }
                ]
        }
}
module.exports = config
```

**Contents of app/index.jsx:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      return (
        <p>Hello world!</p>
      );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Contents of package.json**

```
me@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial$ cat package.json
{
  "name": "reactjstutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "checking out babel",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

**Other questions**

I was expecting to see a bundled js file in by build folder but it's currently empty
Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?  thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Thanks for the responses guys.  FWIW … I'd like to try manually so I actually understand what's happening under the hood first.  Ultimately, instead of building my own application, I have to take over a massive react/nodejs app that others have written.  so this is why if possible, i'd like to know how everything fits together.
Having said that, i'll do both.  I'll create the html file and try to play around.  And then I'll take your suggestion and also try using the create react app tool

Thnks.

**EDIT 2**

This is where my index.html is .. and what it looks like:

```
me@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial$ cat public/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>

me@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial$
```

this is the config now for webpack.  notice the first line now adds require for html-webpack-plugin... and then the corresponding plugins section at the end.

```
me@DESKTOP-123:/mnt/c/Users/me/source/repos/reactjstutorial$ cat webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/build')
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/app')

var config = {
        entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
        mode: 'development',
        output: {
                path: BUILD_DIR,
                filename: 'bundle.js',
                publicPath: '/'
        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        devServer: {
                inline: true,
                contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
                port: 3333
        },
        module: {
                rules: [
                        {
                                test: /\.jsx?/,
                                include: APP_DIR,
                                loader: 'babel-loader'
                        }
                ]
        },
        plugins: [
                new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
                        filename: 'index.html'
                })
        ]
}
module.exports = config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an html file to be served, create `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

then install `html-webpack-plugin` and add it to the webpack config plugins section

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require( 'html-webpack-plugin' );
....

plugins: [
   new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
       template: path.resolve( __dirname, 'public/index.html' ),
       filename: 'index.html'
   })
]
```

also I think since you're using the dev server then maybe files will be served from memory, so you'll not see it in dist folder

P.S. since you're just starting, I suggest you to start with React functional components with hooks instead of using react class components, it's the way to go now and much elegant

**Edit 1**

in html file, div element should have an id of `app` not `root` since in your index.jsx you render to app element

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

also there is no need to tell index.html file the location of your bundle as `HtmlWebPackPlugin` will inject it for you, so the final html file should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

I can't stress enough to use react functional component instead of react class components especially if you're starting out, so here is the same App component using React function :)

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: So I finally got around to trying your suggestion.  Now i no longer get the directory listing ... no errors either.  But no hello world .  Please see my EDIT 2 which shows you what I changed.

Comment: yes, sorry my fault and I just noticed that, your html file the element we need to render to has id of `root` but should be `app`, also there is no need to pass `bundle.js` in html file as HtmlWebPackPlugin will inject it automatically, I'll update my answer

Comment: ok using your edited answer, i was able to get the first approach working.  thanks!  re: edit 2 / functional component, would i just replace the contents of index.jsx with your code in Edit 2? I've given that a try actually and although there are no compile errors, it doesn't actually display hello world.  I"ve accepted your answer though bc solution 1 works.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, no you need to replace App class with the App function code in edit 2, sorry again this is my fault I should have posted the complete code, I just edited the answer again, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that you're not actually compiling or building anything. You're running the dev server before you've given anything to run.

I suggest you use Create React App or an alternative, as doing this all manually is quite the task.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). It does all the work of setting it all up for you. Getting webpack working fully-featured takes a lot of configuring and tweaking.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

This will create a boilerplate React project inside a folder named `my-app` in the current directory.

Comment: While I agree that create-react-app does help a lot to quickly get started, being able to configure webpack is a pretty good skillset to have :)